# how to select and display products in an array, sorted by same product name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called products, here is the part which is relevant:

```
id, company_id, product_name, product_version
```

products can have duplicate names but different ids and versions. Here is an example (made up things) entry:

```
 1, 24, Kool, default version
 2, 24, Kool, mega edition
 3, 24, Kool, pink edition
 4, 24, Kool, limited edition
 5, 24, Something, default version
 6, 24, Something, v2
 7, 24, Anotherone, default version
 8, 24, Last, default version
 9, 24, Last, special edition
10, 56, Bloop, default version
11, 56, Bloop, second edition
```

To fetch this data I have the following php:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "
SELECT p.*
     , c.company_name 
  FROM products p
  JOIN company c
    ON p.company_id = c.id 
 ORDER 
    BY c.company_name
     , p.id
     , p.product_name");
```

Then I display it using:

```
$group1 = array();
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$group1[ $row1['company_name'] ][] = $row1;
}

foreach ($group1 as $company_name => $models) {
    echo "$company_name\n"; 
    echo "</br>";

foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo '<div id="product">';
        echo "<a href='index.php?id=$model[id]'>";
        echo "<img src='$product_image_url'>"; // this variable is set earlier.
        echo '</a>';
        echo "<p>$model_name</p>"; // this variable is set earlier.
    echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '<div id="clear"></div>'; // clear float: left before next company.
    }
```

This displays like this:

```
COMPANY 1
PRODUCT 1, PRODUCT 2, PRODUCT 3

COMPANY 2
PRODUCT 1, PRODUCT 2
```

But I want each line of products (under each company) to only be products that share the same product_name.

For example, for all products under company id '24' (aka COMPANY 1 below), I want any item that has product_name = Kool to be grouped, and then the array starts again for the next item....so like this:

```
COMPANY 1
Kool, Kool, Kool, Kool
Something, Something
Anotherone
Last, Last

COMPANY 2
Bloop, Bloop
Lunto
Wolli, Wolli

COMPANY 3
and so on...
```

I've been messing around with the code all day but can't figure it out. My brain would appreciate any help on what to do.

edit in reply to Shutterfly:

That code is giving me this output:

```
COMPANY 1
Kool, Kool, Kool, Kool

COMPANY 1
Something, Something

COMPANY 1
Anotherone

COMPANY 1
Last, Last

COMPANY 2
and so on...
```

I only want *one* company heading for all of that companies products. But the way the products are displaying thanks to your code is beautiful! That part works.

What can I change to make it only one company heading?

Comment: Do you have products with the same id but different names!?!?

Comment: Nope, other way around. Products can have the same name (but different product_version), but they each have a unique id.

Comment: So sorting by id then name ain't gonna do much for you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is with this?

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
  $result[ $row1['company_name'] ][ $row1['product_name'] ][] = $row1;
}

foreach ($result as $company_name => $products_group) {
  echo $company_name;
  foreach ($products_group as $group_name => $products) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
      // do something...
    }

    echo "<br />";
  }

  echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, that ALMOST works exactly the way I am trying to get it to... see the edit in my original post, right at the bottom :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. See my changed example.

Comment: I did misunderstand, it's working perfectly. I need to read up about multiple foreach loops etc. Thanks a lot for your help!